# setInterval that takes into account function time of run

Tags: javascript

I need function that execute some payload functions once in a while but takes into account that

- a) payload function can takes some time to finish (like axaj request with timeout)
- b) payload function can be Promise
- c) I might wanna stop it some time later

Answer (score 2):

To easy, just use the new ESnext async / await syntax to make it easy. At first we need a small helper timer:

```
const time = ms => new Promise(res => setTimeout(res, ms));
```

To be used like this:

```
(async function(){
   while(true){
       await whatever(); // whatever shall be a promise
       //wait some time:
       await time(1000);
   }
})()
```

Comment: So `whatever()` have to be a Promise wrapper around real function:
`await Promise.resolve(whatever());`, right?

How should I use the construction you offer?

Comment: @totalamd if its a normal function just do `whatever()`, if its something asynchronous ( thats what were talkig about here) that function should return a promise, and then you simply do `await whatever()`

Comment: But there's no way to check out is `whatever()` promise or not (except checking `.then()` method presenting) so I need to wrap in in promise anyway.

Comment: @totalamd no you don't need to. Await does not require a promise

Comment: @"jonas-w" but how to make this loop stop?

Comment: @totalamd simply use a flag.

Comment: @@jonas-w: I want to return object to be able to stop infinite loop. Smth like `return { stop: () => { flag = false; } }`, but `async function` always return Promise. Can I make it without using wrapper async function inside?

Comment: `let stop = false` globally, then `if(stop) return;` inside the async functions loop, then you can do `stop = true` somewhen

Answer (score 0):

With a great appreciation to https://www.thecodeship.com/web-development/alternative-to-javascript-evil-setinterval/ and small improvements by me I'm posting this solution, feel free to correct me.

```js
function interval(func, wait, times) {
  var _interval = function () {
    if (typeof times === "undefined" || times-- > 0) {
      try {
        Promise.resolve(func())
          .then(() => { window.setTimeout(_interval, wait) });
      }
      catch (e) {
        times = 0;
        throw e.toString();
      }
    }
  };

  _interval();

  return { stop: () => { times = 0 } };
};
```

`interval()` returns object with `stop` field so you can run it to stop timer like:

```js
let timer = interval(func, 1000, 10);
...
timer.stop();
```

Comment: You have to consider the license when copying work from other sites. Since the site you copied the work from does not mention any license, you need to consider it as all rights reserved, and are not allowed to make copies of the content

Comment: So... what I need to do now?